# Add active class to parent li when child link is active

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navigation with dropdowns and want to have a different style on the link if you're on a page under that section. I'm using mostly Bootstrap so there's a lot of css. Here's what the HTML looks like for a couple of the sections:

```
<li class='dropdown'>
    <a href='#' class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown'>General Info<span class='caret'></span></a>
    <ul class='dropdown-menu' role='menu'>
        <li><a href='/email_list.php'>Employee Directory</a></li>
        <li><a href='/docs.php'>Documents</a></li>
        <li><a href='/ftp.php'>FTP</a></li>
        <li><a href='/manage/'>Manage</a></li>
        <li><a href='/flyspray'>Bug/Feature Tracking</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class='dropdown'>
    <a href='#' class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown'>Job Info<span class='caret'></span></a>
    <ul class='dropdown-menu' role='menu'>
        <li><a href='/job/list'>Job List</a></li>
        <li><a href='/files_required.php'>Files Rqrd</a></li>
        <li><a href='/incoming_list.php'>Incoming Data List</a></li>
        <li><a href='/signoff.php'>Signoffs</a></li>
        <li><a href='/leader_list2.php'>Leader List</a></li>
        <li><a href='/milestones'>Milestone/Timelines</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

So for example if someone is on the Job List page, Job Info would be highlighted.

**EDIT:** I know this can't be done with just CSS. Looking for an answer using JavaScript or PHP. 
Thank you

Comment: CSS has no parent selector, nor does it know the URL that it has been requested using.

Comment: Yes, but I know there is a way that this is possible. I'm assuming using PHP or JavaScript?

Comment: Oh, sure. You didn't mention that you could use JavaScript or PHP.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to put it in when writing. I can use them though for sure. The most simple method would be prefered though

Comment: Adding a `current` class using PHP and adding a style for that class would be your best bet. You can use `$_SERVER` to find out which page has been requested.

Comment: @George, agreed.. would also need to figure a way to apply class to parent li, hence my in favor of simplicity answer with jQuery. lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compare the link's `href` to `location.pathname` and transverse up the dom to add an `active` class

Here is a [**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/djz6pdm0/6/)

**jQuery**

When a link's `href` equals the current path name (`/link.php`), it will be given an `active` class and  the `li` with a class of `dropdown` that link is within will be given an`active` class, allowing you to style them.

```
$('.dropdown a').filter(function(){

    return $(this).attr('href') == location.pathname

}).addClass('active').closest('ul').parent().addClass('active');
```

**CSS**

Use `nth-child` to get a child element selected by index, basically - choose which active dropdown to style

```
.dropdown.active:nth-child(1) { 
    /* first dropdown */
}

.dropdown.active:nth-child(2) { 
    /* second dropdown */
}

.dropdown a.active {
    /* any active link */
}
```

---

**Extra Class Option**

Using the above jQuery, you can add a class to  each `.dropdown` to style individually with more readability

Here is a **[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/djz6pdm0/5/)**

**HTML**

```
<li class='general-info dropdown'>
    <ul class='dropdown-menu' role='menu'>
    <!-- -->
    </ul>
</li>

<li class='job-info dropdown'>
    <ul class='dropdown-menu' role='menu'>
    <!-- -->
    </ul>
</li>
```

**CSS**

```
.general-info.active {
    /* first dropdown */
}   

.job-info.active {
    /* second dropdown */
}    

.dropdown a.active {
    /* any active link */
}
```

Comment: Okay I'm trying to get this to work. Problem is the nav list is generated using PHP so when I make the classes the names have spaces. Working on it now and will get back to you. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Added an update to my answer if you'd like to avoid adding classes

Answer (score 2):

You can't set styles on the elements depending on the URL.

The most ideal way to implement what you have questioned would be adding the class to the dropdown using server-side scripts like PHP.

The example code is:

menu.php

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li <?php echo ($page == 'page1') ? 'class="current"' : '';?>> <a href="#">Page1</a> </li>
    <li <?php echo ($page == 'page2') ? 'class="current"' : '';?>> <a href="#">Page2</a></li>   
</ul>
```

and your php page where you want to include the menu:

```
<?php     
    $page = 'page1';
    include('menu.php');
?>
```

and set the style for the `current` class in CSS.

Comment: This is my 1st choice, using an `include` trick and some redirections in an `.htaccess` file. It gives you fine-tunning on your website.

Comment: The OP needs how `$page` is set and also how the logic of a child link can add a class of `current` to the parent level `li` Would need some logic with `$_SERVER` to determine current url and some array fiddling to determine the child links parent class to answer the question, but generally I agreed with server side first

Answer (score 0):

Try This it should work.

```js
 var url = "http://" + "<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>";
        $('ul.nav a[href="' + url + '"]').parent().addClass('active2');
        $('.dropdown a').filter(function () {
            return $(this).attr('href') == url
        }).closest('ul').parent().addClass('active2');
```

Comment: it will find the current URL and it's parent and set  active both(child and parent menu)